# How to know if Observable changed value or final value was set

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular7, angular-observable

I have a variable of type `returnDate: Observable<string>` which value is set from another function of type Observable, which looks something like:

```
getDates(): Observable<string> {
   return new Observable((observer) => { 
   observer.next(moment(this.data.Date).format('DD MMM'));}
   });
 }
```

Now how can I detect or know if returnDate value has been changed or if the observable has received another value.
Basicly I am changing dates with this observables so i need to know for a specific object (this.data.Date) if the given value has been changed (the observer.next) was completed or maybe there is a helper function like final/finalaize for the observables.

Comment: Check this out: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~ObserverDoc.html. `complete` may be what you need.

Comment: Maybe I put the question bad, but basically i need to compare the first value that observer has received async and see if it's different with the next one. I am not sure how can oberver.complete() function of type void help with this.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using a [Subject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/Subject) for this. I am assuming that somewhere you know that the data, or date, has changed. With a Subject, you can run *next*, or *complete*, when the data changes. Then, any component that subscribes to the Subject will know. As far as comparing one date to another, you will have to hold the value in a variable and check if they are different when you make a call to the `getDates` function.

Comment: @user4005469 your observable only ever emits one value, so your question is quite hard to understand: there will never be any next date. Step back, and explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: So i have an object with few items with a date property. I am listing them and get the dates by observable. Upon refresh the page or if you change the date for one of this object, i want to know which one has the date changed from the previous observable call. So maybe map them and compare or something, I have tried to use a Subscriber but not sure how can I know which one has the date changed.

Answer (score 4):

Although its difficult to understand from the code you shared how exactly you are doing this. But as far as you question goes -

> so i need to know for a specific object (this.data.Date) if the given
>   value has been changed

In case of rxjs observables, there is an operator distinctUntilChanged which serves  exactly the same purpose. Read [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged.html).

> Only emit when the current value is different than the last.

A sample solution

```
getDates.pipe(distinctUntilChanged())
  .subscribe(data => console.log("This will only hit if data changed"));
```

See if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

if you every time return a `new Observable()` where you'll subscribe you'll get different values for example you return a `return new Observable(Math.random()*10)` and you subscribed in 2 components you'll get different values, but i think you need to get same value, so for this scenario use `Subject()`

First you have to declare it then set value and then return `this.subject.asObservable()` this gives you opportunity to subscribe to this subject.

Simple example

```
  // set initial value to subject, ussualy set data above constructor
  dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  // then you get data from server
  // response can be data from serve or data from eventEmitter whatever you need

  this.dataSubject.next(response);

  // then return this subject

  return this.dataSubject.asObservable()
```

In this case use BehaviorSubject because it can hold value and also you can set initial value of the subject

If you have more question feel free to ask.